# Get a node by its ID

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to create graph with `mNode` as nodes and `mLink` as links.
In the following code, `otherLink` has `source` & `target` fields which refers to the nodes connected to this link.
`otherLink.source` is just an object with the node data, for example:

```
{"id": 1,
 "index: 0,
 ...
}
```

How do apply style on this node (look at the `// DOESN'T WORK` line below:

```
function Graph(elementId) {
  var svg;
  var simulation;
  var mNodesData = [];
  var mEdgesData = [];
  var mNode = null;
  var mLink = null;
  var elementId;
  var heightDelta = 100;
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight - heightDelta;

  return {
      init: function () {
          svg = d3.select('#' + elementId)
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

          simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
              .force(".edge", d3.forceLink())
              .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-600))
              .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

          mLink = svg.selectAll(".edge")
              .attr("class", "edge")
              .style("stroke", LINK_DEFAULT_COLOR)
              .style("stroke-width", function (e) {
                  return 1
                  /* e.width*/
              });

          mNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .attr("class", "node");
      },
      draw: function () {
          mLink = svg.selectAll(".edge")
              .data(mEdgesData)
              .enter()
              .append("line")
              .attr("class", "edge")
              .style("stroke", LINK_DEFAULT_COLOR)
              .style("stroke-width", function (e) {
                  return 2
                  /* e.width*/
              }).merge(mLink).lower();

          mNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(mNodesData)
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "node").merge(mNode);

          mNode.call(d3.drag()
              .on("start", dragstarted)
                  .on("drag", dragged)
                  .on("end", dragended));

          mNode.on('mouseover', function (currentNode) {
              mLink.filter(function (otherLink) {
                  if (currentNode !== otherLink.source) {
                      otherLink.source.style("opacity", BACKGROUND_OPACITY); // DOESN'T WORK
                  }
                  return (currentNode !== otherLink.source && currentNode !== otherLink.target);
              }).style("opacity", BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
              mLink.filter(function (otherLink) {
                  return (currentNode == otherLink.source || currentNode == otherLink.target);
              }).style("opacity", DEFAULT_OPACITY);
          });

          simulation.nodes(mNodesData);
          simulation.force(".edge").links(mEdgesData);
      }
  }
}
```

full code: [here](https://github.com/itayB/d3-graph/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Since nobody answered this yet, I wrote another answer. Please tell me if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `currentNode` and `otherLink.source` in your code are the data of those elements. Therefore, to get the IDs, you have to use their properties. For example, in your conditional:

```
if (currentNode.id !== otherLink.source.id)
//property here--^----------------------^
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the ID of the node (or nodes) connected to a given node when you `mouseover` it, and then changing the style of that connected node (or any other change you want).

Here is a possible solution. First, on `mouseover`, we get the ID of the current node:

```
mNode.on('mouseover', function(currentNode) {
    var thisNodeID = currentNode.id;
```

Then, we use that ID to populate an array with the ID (or IDs, if more than one) of the connected node (or nodes):

```
var connectedNodes = mEdgesData.filter(function(d){
    return d.source.id === thisNodeID || d.target.id === thisNodeID
}).map(function(d){
    return d.source.id === thisNodeID ? d.target.id : d.source.id
});
```

Finally, we use `indexOf` to check what nodes are in that list:

```
mNode.filter(function(d){
  return connectedNodes.indexOf(d.id) > -1
}).style("opacity", DEFAULT_OPACITY);
```

All together, it would be:

```
mNode.on('mouseover', function(currentNode) {
    var thisNodeID = currentNode.id;
    var connectedNodes = mEdgesData.filter(function(d) {
        return d.source.id === thisNodeID || d.target.id === thisNodeID
    }).map(function(d) {
        return d.source.id === thisNodeID ? d.target.id : d.source.id
    });
    mNode.filter(function(d) {
        return connectedNodes.indexOf(d.id) > -1
    }).style("opacity", DEFAULT_OPACITY);
});
```

Since you didn't provide a running code, here is an example of that `mouseover` snippet based on a bl.ocks from Mike Bostock, where I'm changing the connected nodes to red: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/0db9b4307a1ff6724f89c932f55f6508/2a6cfa3a8bfb03cfa368033faa3804ae5601e403

Comment: great! follow up question here ;-) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919293/d3-js-javascript-efficient-code

Comment: as d3.js master, I'll appreciate if you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026059/d3-js-graph-is-broken-after-adding-new-nodes