# d3.js / javascript efficient code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following `filter` is the same, but it result applied for two different element:

```
mNode.filter(function(otherNode) {
    return connectedNodes.indexOf(otherNode.id) > -1
}).select("image").style("opacity", BACKGROUND_OPACITY);

mNode.filter(function (otherNode) {
    return connectedNodes.indexOf(otherNode.id) > -1;
}).select("circle").style("stroke", "#f6f6f6");
```

how can I combine it to one `filter` without duplicate the code?

second, is there a way to apply to opposite more efficient?

```
mNode.filter(function(otherNode) {
     return connectedNodes.indexOf(otherNode.id) > -1
}).select("image").style("opacity", BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
mNode.filter(function(otherNode) {
      return connectedNodes.indexOf(otherNode.id) == -1
}).select("image").style("opacity", DEFAULT_OPACITY);
```

Like if the condition is satisfied apply 1st style otherwise apply the 2nd style.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `for` to iterate over `mNode`, inside it, use `if...else` and apply styles.

Comment: @Tushar that `mNode` is not an array and that filter is not `Array.prototype.filter`, that's a different method with the same name (that's confusing, I know...). So, the `for` won't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question: just use a selection:

```
var filtered = mNode.filter(function(otherNode) {
    return connectedNodes.indexOf(otherNode.id) > -1
});
```

And then:

```
filtered.select("image").style("opacity", BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
filtered.select("circle").style("stroke", "#f6f6f6");
```

Your second question is a bit more complicated, and has different solutions. I'd use an `each` to check every node. Something like:

```
mNode.each(function(d) {
  if (connectedNodes.indexOf(d.id) > -1) {
    d3.select(this).select("image").style("opacity", BACKGROUND_OPACITY);
  } else {
    d3.select(this).select("image").style("opacity", DEFAULT_OPACITY);
  }
})
```

However, I'd say that, intuitively, your code is faster than the `each`. You can always test both solutions using tools like [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/).

Comment: I'm trying to work with 'each', but then I don't know how to apply the style on the node (from it's id)

Comment: It is `d3.select(this).style(etc...)`